# Angular Ngrx with Promise service gives error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot freeze`

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am using `ngrx` for state management in my angular application.
My login service returns a promise.

On submitting form i am getting error in console: ERROR TypeError: Cannot freeze

Here is my Effect Code:

```
export class LoginEffects {
  login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(LoginActions.login),
      switchMap((action) =>
        from(this.authService.login(action.username, action.password))
      ),
      catchError((error) => of(LoginActions.loginError(error))),
      map((user) => LoginActions.loginSuccess(user))
    )
  );

  // ... other effects
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
}
```

Here is my login service

```
async login(username, password) {
    return await Auth.signIn(username, password);
}
```

If i change code in my service like this then i don't get any error:

```
login(username, password) {
    return "Login success";
}
```

Whenever service returns a promise i am getting this error.

Comment: What if you remove `from(this.authService.login(action.username, action.password))` and use `this.authService.login(action.username, action.password)` directly?

Comment: @AndreiGătej Still getting same error.